# How to validate textField against regex and show error message in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to achieve that functionality of textfield that if someone done with writing textfield and mark it done or we can say unfocused the textfield then textfield validate input in it and show error message if it doesn't match with given regex. I wanted to validate email formate. When user enter email and move and mark done then textfield validate that if email is valid or not. Also I want my form button to be enabled only when every field is according to regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the validator from TextFormField

```
final emailAddressRegex = RegExp(r'^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$');
Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: new ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
        maxLines: 1,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
        autofocus: false,
        decoration: new InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Email',
            icon: new Icon(
              Icons.mail,
              color: Colors.grey,
            )),
        validator: (value) => value.isEmpty ? 'Email can\'t be empty' : emailAddressRegex.hasMatch(value) ? null : "Enter a valid email address",
        onSaved: (value) => _email = value.trim(),
      ),
      confirmButton(),
    ]
    ),
  ),

Widget confirmButton(){
   return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text("Confirm"),
          onPressed: _formKey.currentState.validate() ? (){
              //send data
          } : null,
      ),
    );
}
```

Comment: No, please don't use this regex to validate email.  It's wrong.  The shortest regex to validate an email address is about 2400 characters, and is given in https://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html.  Anything shorter is WRONG, unless you're using a grammar, as package:email_validator properly does.  Use that for Dart/Flutter please.